# HDFStore Term memory efficient way to check for membership in list

Tags: pandas, hdfstore

I have a pandas HDFStore that I am try to select from.  I would like to select data between a two timestamps with an id in a large np.array.  The following code works but takes up too much memory only when queried for membership in a list.  If I use a datetimeindex and a range, the memory footprint is 95% less.

```
#start_ts, end_ts are timestamps
#instruments is an array of python objects

not_memory_efficient = adj_data.select("US", [Term("date",">=", start_ts),
                              Term("date", "<=", end_ts),
                              Term("id", "=", instruments)])
memory_efficient = adj_data.select("US", [Term("date",">=", start_ts),
                              Term("date", "<=", end_ts),)
```

Is there a more memory efficient way to do this in HDFStore?  Should I set the index to the "sec_id"?  (I can also use the chunksize option and concat myself, but that seems to be a bit of a hack.)

Edits:

The hdfstore is created by pd.HDFStore creating a dataframe and storing such as this.  I made a mistake earlier

```
def write_data(country_data, store_file):
    for country in country_data:
        if len(country_data[country]) == 0:
            continue
        df = pd.concat(country_data[country], ignore_index=True)
        country_data[country] = []
        store_file.append(country, df, format="t")
```

As requested, here is the ptdump for this table: https://gist.github.com/MichaelWS/7980846
also, here is the df: https://gist.github.com/MichaelWS/7981451

Comment: pls detail a sample of data and how u stored it (the code)

Comment: also pls post  ptdump -av file.h5

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I do nothing fancy on storing it other than using ptrepack on it afterwards for compression.  could compression be the issue?

Comment: the code above does not match the Table that is written in the linked file. pls show what you are selecting (actual code) and what works fast and what does not. The more information you provide the better I would be able to help.

Comment: Jeff, I updated sec_id and dt in the dataframe.  Sorry, I had to update "sec_id" and "dt" to "id" and "date".  This code sample I have is direct from the code.

Comment: you are creating a Fixed store (called Storer in 0.12) in the above code, but it appears that you have a Table in the link.

Comment: pls show a sample of the actual DataFrame as well

Comment: can u explain the two approaches you are doing more fully? again actual code is better than words

Comment: are u using 0.13rc1 ?

Comment: no,Should I be using 0.13rc1?

Comment: 0.12 is fine; FYI the format keyword doesn't do anything with append (and it's for 0.13 anyhow); append always is a table

Comment: you need to make id a data_column otherwise the selection ignores it (in 0.13 I believe your code will raise as it will detect this); hence u r reading in the entire data set then reindexing which is not efficient at all.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, that was it.  I really appreciate your help.  I was not sure what I was doing wrong.

I have not switched 0.13rc1 because I use some of the functionality of talib that does not work.

Comment: what functionality does not work?

Comment: essentially, I need to edit a lot of code to call with the values instead of just calling a series.

  My other pressing issue in 0.13 is the way I have been using groupby.transform now throws errors.  
the line throws an exception for 0.13rc1 and does not in 0.12 
   cik_df["daily_ranks"] = cik_df.groupby("ex_date")["value"].transform(lambda x: x.rank())

Comment: why would you have to change to call with a Series? virtually everything should work transparently, if not pls file a bug report

Comment: the pandas Series has been refactored. I have to refactor my code.

"
Warning In 0.13.0 since Series has internaly been refactored to no longer sub-class ndarray but instead subclass NDFrame, you can not pass a Series directly as a ndarray typed parameter to a cython function. Instead pass the actual ndarray using the .values attribute of the Series."

Comment: that is the exception. Where do you you use cython? (I did the refactoring FYI).

Comment: Oh great. Should we take this to a discussion?  
talib uses cython for every call. all of my calls to cython work fine.  I used .values and .index for my own pieces.

Comment: also, should I have in the ptdump  the wrong version of pandas. in ipython, its "0.12.0"
    pandas_version := '0.10.1',

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43277/discussion-between-jeff-and-michael-ws)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To memorialize this for other users.

In HDFStore, is required to designate certain columns as data_columns if they are not the index in order to later query then.

Docs are [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#query-via-data-columns)

Create a frame

```
In [23]: df = DataFrame(dict(date = pd.date_range('20130101',periods=10), id = list('abcabcabcd'), C = np.random.randn(10)))


In [28]: df
Out[28]: 
          C                date id
0  0.605701 2013-01-01 00:00:00  a
1  0.451346 2013-01-02 00:00:00  b
2  0.479483 2013-01-03 00:00:00  c
3 -0.012589 2013-01-04 00:00:00  a
4 -0.028552 2013-01-05 00:00:00  b
5  0.737100 2013-01-06 00:00:00  c
6 -1.050292 2013-01-07 00:00:00  a
7  0.137444 2013-01-08 00:00:00  b
8 -0.327491 2013-01-09 00:00:00  c
9 -0.660220 2013-01-10 00:00:00  d

[10 rows x 3 columns]
```

Save to hdf WITHOUT data_columns

```
In [24]: df.to_hdf('test.h5','df',mode='w',format='table')
```

0.13 will report this error (0.12 will just silently ignore)

```
In [25]: pd.read_hdf('test.h5','df',where='date>20130101 & date<20130105 & id=["b","c"]')
 ValueError: The passed where expression: date>20130101 & date<20130105 & id=["b","c"]
            contains an invalid variable reference
            all of the variable refrences must be a reference to
            an axis (e.g. 'index' or 'columns'), or a data_column
            The currently defined references are: index,columns
```

Set all the columns as data columns (can also be a specific list of columns)

```
In [26]: df.to_hdf('test.h5','df',mode='w',format='table',data_columns=True)

In [27]: pd.read_hdf('test.h5','df',where='date>20130101 & date<20130105 & id=["b","c"]')
Out[27]: 
          C                date id
1  0.451346 2013-01-02 00:00:00  b
2  0.479483 2013-01-03 00:00:00  c

[2 rows x 3 columns]
```

Here is a the Table node of `ptdump -av` of the file:

```
/df/table (Table(10,)) ''
  description := {
  "index": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=0),
  "C": Float64Col(shape=(), dflt=0.0, pos=1),
  "date": Int64Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=2),
  "id": StringCol(itemsize=1, shape=(), dflt='', pos=3)}
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (2621,)
  autoindex := True
  colindexes := {
    "date": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
    "index": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
    "C": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False,
    "id": Index(6, medium, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=False}
  /df/table._v_attrs (AttributeSet), 19 attributes:
   [CLASS := 'TABLE',
    C_dtype := 'float64',
    C_kind := ['C'],
    FIELD_0_FILL := 0,
    FIELD_0_NAME := 'index',
    FIELD_1_FILL := 0.0,
    FIELD_1_NAME := 'C',
    FIELD_2_FILL := 0,
    FIELD_2_NAME := 'date',
    FIELD_3_FILL := '',
    FIELD_3_NAME := 'id',
    NROWS := 10,
    TITLE := '',
    VERSION := '2.7',
    date_dtype := 'datetime64',
    date_kind := ['date'],
    id_dtype := 'string8',
    id_kind := ['id'],
    index_kind := 'integer']
```

The key thing to note is that the data_columns are separate in the 'description', AND they are setup as indexes.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot supply a large list to be selected through and not have the entire pandas object loaded into memory. This is a limit in how numexpr operates.

pandas issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5717

pytables issue: http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=30390757